# How can I get unique records via query builder in Laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am new to Laravel,
can anyone help me with this how should I get unique records through this query in laravel query builder?

as of now, I'm getting duplicate records for example *red, pink, red, pink, green*

here is my query

**MySQL query:**

`` select count(*) as aggregate from (select `product`.`id`, `name`, `category`.`category`, group_concat(product_synonyms.product_synonym)as product_synonym, group_concat(product_tags.product_tag) as product_tag from `product` left join `product_tags` on `product`.`id` = `product_tags`.`product_id` left join `category` on `category`.`id` = `product`.`category_id` left join `product_synonyms` on `product`.`id` = `product_synonyms`.`product_id` where `user_id` = 1 and `product`.`deleted_at` is null group by `product_tags`.`product_id`) as `aggregate_table`; ``

**Query builder:**

```
Product::leftJoin('product_tags', 'product.id', 'product_tags.product_id')
            ->leftJoin('category', 'category.id', 'product.category_id')
            ->leftJoin('product_synonyms', 'product.id', 'product_synonyms.product_id')
            ->where('user_id', auth()->user()->id)
            ->select('product.id', 'name','category.category',DB::raw('group_concat(product_synonyms.product_synonym)as product_synonym'),DB::raw('group_concat(product_tags.product_tag)) as product_tag')
            ->groupBy('product_tags.product_id')
            ->orderBy('product.name', 'ASC')
            ->paginate(10);
```

I tried with different join and did many changes, seem I missing something and I couldn't figure it out, and
ending with expecting something from a helping hand

Comment: using `distinct()`

Comment: Take a look at https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-unique or https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp

Comment: Can you share more details? How should `select count(*)` return duplicate records?

Comment: @Basharmal @jerry555555 thanks, why couldn't I think about this function, this one helps :)
with the use of  ```distinct()```  it doesn't return duplicate

Answer (score 0):

For get only one result in your query you need use:

```
$productDetails = Product::leftJoin('product_tags', 'product.id', 'product_tags.product_id')
            ->leftJoin('category', 'category.id', 'product.category_id')
            ->leftJoin('product_synonyms', 'product.id', 'product_synonyms.product_id')
            ->where('user_id', auth()->user()->id)
            ->select('product.id', 'name','category.category',DB::raw('group_concat(product_synonyms.product_synonym)as product_synonym')**->first();**
```

for example.

Paginate if you need more result of query. If you need more than one result use `->get()`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
Product::leftJoin('product_tags', 'product.id', 'product_tags.product_id')
        ->leftJoin('category', 'category.id', 'product.category_id')
        ->leftJoin('product_synonyms', 'product.id', 'product_synonyms.product_id')
        ->where('user_id', auth()->user()->id)
        ->select('product.id', 'name','category.category',DB::raw('group_concat(product_synonyms.product_synonym)as product_synonym'),DB::raw('group_concat(product_tags.product_tag)) as product_tag')
         ->distinct()
        ->groupBy('product_tags.product_id')
        ->orderBy('product.name', 'ASC')
        ->paginate(10);
```